# How to achieve this zooming and unzooming functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to achieving this effect from Mozilla Firefox, when clicking on a video thumbnail. I would also like to achieve this with photos as well. [Check this link](http://en-gb.www.mozilla.com/en-GB/firefox/3.5.1/whatsnew/) and click on the thumbnail play button.

Comment: Tony, would you try describing the effect that you saw, in a question edit? I cannot see it at the link here, so assume that a Mozilla redesign has removed what you wanted to do. You may know that link-only questions here tend to be closed, so if you can beef this up a bit, that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, there's lots of plugins to provide zoom style thumb-to-full-size effects. For example [fancybox](http://fancy.klade.lv/) (see the third single image example on [this page](http://fancy.klade.lv/example)).

Alternatively, if you want more control, you could build the features yourself without too much effort:

1. Load the full image with [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype)
2. Replace the `src` [attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue) of your thumbnail image (make sure its a fixed size)
3. Do the zoom by [animating](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback) your width/height (& position if necessary) to the full size of the final image

Note that depending on what you're showing (for example if you were doing this for embedded flash video), you may need to swap the order of 2 & 3, by zooming the thumbnail (or some other place holder image) & then swapping in the final, full size content.